# Prove any integer can be written as a combination of 2s and 5s

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Given any $n \in\mathbb{Z}$ greater than $3$, prove that it can be written as a combination of $2$'s and $5$'s.

**No induction!**

Comment: What did you try so far? Remember, this is not a site where we just do the work for you.

Comment: @Bram28 If you don't want to "do the work" for OP, you might try to provide a hint.  That's more likely to engage OP in the problem.

Comment: Raw question without a single  "wrapping" sentence... What work have you done on this problem? We are not there to solve homework at your place. I vote to close.

Comment: @JeanMarie Someone said what you said already.  You don't really have proof that this is homework, and if you are that bothered, you could either just provide a hint or not answer at all.

Comment: @user46944 Thanks, good advice! ... not that I really have a hint ... :/

Comment: @user46944 I wrote my comment without noticing the first one. I no longer povide hints to people that have not the minimum respect to add at least a little sentence. These kind of people lower the global quality of this site.

Comment: Wait, I *do* have a **Hint**: Try and see how you can make the first bunch of numbers (4,5,6,7, etc., maybe go up to 20 or so) from 2's and 5's, and see if you see a pattern

Comment: @JeanMarie I also feel that it lowers the quality of the site to go on a witch hunt any time a question is missing detail.  Your comment is accusatory and the tone it's written in is unpleasant.

Comment: @user46944 So what do we do now? I love to give hints and help people, but people just answer the question .. frustrating to a teacher.

Comment: @Bram28 What do you mean?  You mean with respect to your hint?

Comment: @user46944 No, with respect to people answering the question when we're just trying to nudge the OP along towards understanding.  ... Not that these highly technical answers will probably be understood by the OP anyway ...

Comment: @Bram28 Maybe you can write your hint up as an actual answer, and do a couple of easy cases to show OP how they should proceed. :)

Comment: This isn't part of my work, I just saw this on the internet with people proving it with induction. I'm just bored and trying to prove this without induction. You don't have to answer it if u don't feel like it.

Comment: @user46944 So I can do hints as answers? OK, just did that.

Comment: @Bram28 You can definitely put hints as answers, especially if you start off your answer with "Hint:".  You gave a good answer. +1 :)

Comment: There is a difference between just ignoring a question and pointing out if the questions is impolite, shows no evidence that the poser made any attempt to solve. When it seems just passing the question to someone else to solve such reactions are to be expected and correct. There is a purpose we have the concept of downvoting.(I have done now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to be a smart ass, but there is only one $\mathbb Z$, and that's $\mathbb Z$ itself.

Perhaps what you meant is that any $n \in \mathbb Z$ greater than $3$ can be expressed as a sum of $2$s and $5$s.

You can prove this by examination of cases if you don't like induction. I'll do the first two for you:

- If $n \equiv 1 \pmod 5$, then $n = 5k + 2 + 2 + 2$, where $k > 0$ (and $n > 6$).
- If $n \equiv 2 \pmod 5$, then $n = 5k + 5 + 2$, where $k \geq 0$.

If you get the idea, then you just need to do three more cases, and deal with a few loose ends.

Answer (score 1):

The starting point is that

$5-2.2=1$

thus

$\forall n\geq 3    \; \; n=5n-2(2n)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

OK, try some numbers:

4 = 2+2

5 = 5

6 = 2+2+2

7 = 5+2

8 = 2+2+2+2

9 = 5+2+2

10 = 5+5

11 = 5+2+2+2

12 = 5+5+2

13 = 5+2+2+2+2 (starting to see a pattern yet? if not, continue ...)

14 = 5+5+2+2

15 = 5+5+5

16 = 5+5+2+2+2

17 = 5+5+5+2

18 = 5+5+2+2+2+2 (this should start to look familiar ...)

19 = 5+5+5+2+2

...

Starting to see that pattern? Once you see the pattern, can you turn that into a proof?

**Edit**

This one is probably easier to see:

4 = 2 + 2

5 = 5

6 = 2 + 2 + 2

7 = 2 + 5

8 = 2 + 2 + 2 + 2

9 = 2 + 2 + 5

10 = 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2

11 = 2 + 2 + 2 + 5
...

Answer (score 0):

We have to solve the equation $$2x+5y=n$$

The general solution of the homogenous equation is $(-5t/2t)$

A special solution of $2x+5y=n$ is $(-2n/n)$

Therefore, the general (integer) solution of $2x+5y=n$ is $(-5t-2n/2t+n)$

To have non-negative values , we have to fulfil the conditions

$-5t-2n\ge 0$ and $2t+n\ge 0$. This is equivalent to $t\le -\frac{2}{5}n$ and $t\ge -\frac{1}{2}n$. If $n\ge 10$, the difference between $-\frac{2}{5}n$ and $-\frac{1}{2}n$ is $\ge 1$, so there must be an integer $t$ with the required inequalities. It is easy to verify the numbers $4$ to $9$.